# Android App - Making a calendar that can read an RSS feed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calendar, rss

I am making an android app and want it to show a calendar that has up to date information that is obtained from an RSS feed.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

I've found the RSS feed but haven't found anything that is much help in regards to making the calendar.

Thanks in advance!